# Is This Constraint Convex?

Tags: constraint, convexity, nonconvex-programming, lp-relaxation

I have a constraint that I believe to be convex and not affine which I think means that I can implement a relaxation. I will first define the full constraint, and then build up my (informal) reasoning as to why I think it's convex. Hopefully the holes in my thinking can be pointed out and corrected.

$$   X_{t} = \frac{ Y_{t-1}^2 }{Y_{t-1}^2 + a^2}Z_{t-1}, \quad t=1,2,\dots,T \tag1 $$
$$ X_t,Y_t,Z_t \ge 0, $$
$$ X_0, Y_0, Z_0, \alpha  \gt 0 $$

**Argument 1:**  A quadratic polynomial is convex, so if the constraint was simply $ X_{t} = Y_{t-1}^2$ then the constraint would be convex.

**Argument 2:** By a similar extension, $ X_{t} = Y_{t-1}^2 + \alpha^2 $ would be convex.

**Argument 3:** The ratio of two convex functions, call it $F_{t-1}$, should also be convex.

**Argument 4:** If $F_{t-1}$ is convex, then multiplying $F_{t-1}$ by a continuous linear variable would not impose any non-convexity issues.

**Conclusion:** The original constraint is convex but not affine and as such we can apply a relaxation to change the problem into:

$$   X_{t} \le \frac{ Y_{t-1}^2 }{Y_{t-1}^2 + a^2}Z_{t-1}, \quad t=1,2,\dots,T \tag1 $$

Comment: Even though your argument is not correct, there is still a possibility to obtain a convex formulation. You could substitute all your $X_t$ variables using the equality constraints that you showed us. If you are (really) lucky, it might be that your problem is convex after the substitutions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Arguments 3 and 4 are incorrect. The Right-Hand Side (RHS) is not convex. Even if it were, setting a nonlinear equality with either side non-affine is non-convex. As the final coup de grace, even if the RHS were convex, an inequality, {affine expression} $\le$ {convex RHS}, is going the wrong direction to be convex.

I suggest you study sections 2.3 and especially 3.2, both named "Operations that preserve convexity" of **[Convex Optimization, by Boyd and Vandenberghe](http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf)** which is freely available at the linked website of one of the authors.

Comment: Thank you for the resource! Always appreciate your guidance on the forums.

Comment: Boyd also recommends (jokingly?) to work on this problem in two ways, simultaneously: While you try to prove convexity on paper, you run a program that samples two random points, and checks the convexity of the function at their midpoint, potentially providing a counter-example.

Answer (score 13):

Counterexamples to your arguments:

Argument 1:
Only affine equality constraints are convex, $x = y^2$ is not convex.

Argument 3:
Take $f(x) = x^4$ and $g(x) = x$. Both are convex, but the ratio $h(x) = \frac{x^4}{x} $ is not.

Argument 4:
Let $f(x) = x$, and $y \in \mathbb{R}$. $f$ is convex, but $g(x, y) = yf(x) = xy$ is not.